# How to use a trained alexnet model on my own data?

Tags: tensorflow

https://github.com/guerzh/tf_weights

I have a reference model, (a TensorFlow implementation of AlexNet with pretrained weights) that I wanted to test on my own personal data set of images. Do you guys know what would be the next steps to doing this?